# Как сделать автозаполнение данных в форме?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, как сделать автозаполнение данных в форме, **при выборе того или иного option** в select.

При условии что тот самый option - это id строки из БД, данные которой, соответственно, и нужно подставить в имеющиеся поля формы

Скриншот формы с теми самыми ID,
 которые подгружаются благодаря php циклу вывода данных из таблицы БД 
[image: Скриншот формы]

Скриншот таблицы с данными из таблицы в БД, которые должны заполнятся в доступные поля поля формы выше

Структура таблицы ниже:
ID | *<img src="Данные из третей колонки"> | Ресурс | Категория | Название | Дата 
[image: Скриншот таблицы с данными из таблицы в БД]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например, в каждом теге `<option>` селекта "Выберите ID строки", сделать дата атрибут содержащий JSON-код с соответствующими значениями полей и при выборе пункта из списка получать данные из атрибута выбранного элемента и заполнять остальные поля.

```html
<form>
    <label>Выберите ID строки</label><br>
    <select onchange="fillFormFields(this)">
        <option>...</option>
        <option value="43" data-fields='{"img":"img1.jpg","title":"Название 1"}'>43</option>
        <option value="44" data-fields='{"img":"img2.jpg","title":"Название 2"}'>44</option>
        <!-- ... остальные option -->
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Название"><br>
    <!-- ... остальные поля формы -->
</form>

<script>
// функция для заполнения формы при выборе нового пункта
function fillFormFields(select){
    if(select.selectedIndex > -1){
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        var form = select.form;
        if(option.dataset.fields){
            var fields = JSON.parse(option.dataset.fields);
            // теперь в fields у нас есть данные для заполнения полей
            // Заполняем поле название
            form.title.value = fields.title;
        }else{
            form.title.value = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

На бекэнде JSON можно сформировать фукцией [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) передав в нее массив данных полученных из БД.

Но если данных очень много, то лучше использовать динамическую подгруздку с использованием Ajax.